# Need stripe entire webhooks call history of my account

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I need to check some of the stripe webhook call.But in stripe account only shows last 7 days data.

Any way to get whole webhooks history or atleast 6 months history

Comment: I;m not sure (can't check right now) but there might be a "download all data" setting (for GDPR purposes and such) that you might be able to find, it would include everything else but hopefully there are filters

Comment: oh. Ok.I will check

Comment: No. there is no option for "download all data"

Comment: thanks for your comment.But this is webhooks list. I need each webhook called history

Comment: I see, I misunderstood.  Maybe you can check event history? But looks like max 30 day history: https://support.stripe.com/questions/stripe-event-retention-period, https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/list

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access past *events* you can list those using the [Events List API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/list), optionally filtered by `type` (or an array of `types`). Events are available for 30 days, and you cannot retrieve events older than that.

If you're trying to see a history of API requests to create or modify your webhook *endpoints*, you can review those in your Dashboard developer logs for the endpoint path [`/v1/webhook_endpoints`](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs?showIP=false&method%5B0%5D=post&method%5B1%5D=delete&path=%2Fv1%2Fwebhook_endpoints&direction%5B0%5D=self) (for create calls) or [`/v1/webhook_endpoints/*`](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs?showIP=false&method%5B0%5D=post&method%5B1%5D=delete&path=%2Fv1%2Fwebhook_endpoints%2F*&direction%5B0%5D=self) (for updates to specific endpoints).

Comment: ok.Thanks for your information. But I need 6 months' data. ( Because a rare issue occurred in  the mid of 6 months duration)